# After i add angular universal it started showing NG100 error in terminal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

It runs and runs normally but in the terminal this error pops and in my global error handler it doesn't stop accusing error

```
error RuntimeError: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'ng-untouched': 'true'. Current value: 'false'.. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
    at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (/Users/User/Documents/Company/Bread/Bread.Web/dist/bread-web/server/main.js:64640:11)
    at bindingUpdated (/Users/User/Documents/Company/Bread/Bread.Web/dist/bread-web/server/main.js:70853:17)
    at checkStylingProperty (/Users/User/Documents/Company/Bread/Bread.Web/dist/bread-web/server/main.js:74644:32)
    at Module.ɵɵclassProp (/Users/User/Documents/Company/Bread/Bread.Web/dist/bread-web/server/main.js:74552:5)
    at NgControlStatusGroup_HostBindings (/Users/User/Documents/Company/Bread/Bread.Web/dist/bread-web/server/main.js:92570:66)
    at processHostBindingOpCodes (/Users/User/Documents/Company/Bread/Bread.Web/dist/bread-web/server/main.js:67096:17)
    at refreshView (/Users/User/Documents/Company/Bread/Bread.Web/dist/bread-web/server/main.js:67375:9)
    at refreshComponent (/Users/User/Documents/Company/Bread/Bread.Web/dist/bread-web/server/main.js:68500:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (/Users/User/Documents/Company/Bread/Bread.Web/dist/bread-web/server/main.js:67125:9)
    at refreshView (/Users/User/Documents/Company/Bread/Bread.Web/dist/bread-web/server/main.js:67379:13) {
  code: '100'
}
```